# UNITY 2D: Player flying when space/mousebutton is holded

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

So basicy i need my character to go up when `space` or `mousebutton` are pressed. I added rigbody 2d and box colider 2d to my `gameobject` (player). The problem is when I hit `space` or `mousebutton`it only jump not constantly **moving up.**

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PixelMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
    public Vector3 PressVelocity;
    public float maxSpeed = 5f;
    public float fowardSpeed = 1f;
    public float jumpForce;

    bool didPress = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    //Do Graphic & Input updates
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            didPress = true;
        }
    }

    //Do physics engine updates here
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        velocity.x = fowardSpeed;
        if (didPress == true)
        {
            didPress = false;
            velocity += PressVelocity * Time.deltaTime *jumpForce;

        }

        velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(velocity, maxSpeed);
        transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code and works fine on my computer. [Here I left a link with the video](https://youtu.be/-JzNxQdYJMs). Have you any other script atached to this GameObject?

Comment: It's `2d` not `3d`

Comment: I attached `box colider 2d` and uncheck `is triggered` and i also added `rigbody2d`

Comment: Have you set the RigitBody2D Mass to zero?

Comment: No, i use auto mass, i fixed this problem but now i have problem with gravity. If i use gravity scale to 1 my object fall down rough, instantly, not like circural...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this works for me. Thanks everyone for help :)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PixelMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public float playerSpeed;
    public Vector3 gravity;
    public float maxSpeed = 5f;
    Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
    public float fowardSpeed = 1f;

    bool didPress = false;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            didPress = true;
        }
        else
        {
            didPress = false;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        velocity.x = fowardSpeed;
        transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
        if (didPress == true)
        {

            float amntToMove1 = playerSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.Translate(Vector3.up * amntToMove1);
        }
        velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(velocity, maxSpeed);
        transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        didPress = true;
    }
    else
    {
        didPress = false;
    }
```

and remove `didPress = false;` from `FixedUpdate()` function

**EDIT:** Ok, wait, I just noticed you update transform.position in `FixedUpdate()` which is not really a good idea. When you do so you basically teleport your object from one position to another ignoring all kinds of physics (which probably is the reason you are using FixedUpdate()). With your script colliding with other objects will give you weird results. Find a tutorial on using RigidBodies to do proper physics-aware movement, or just move all your code to `Update()` because right now you might have some frames where your object doesn't move and other frames where it moves twice the distance. This will happen because `FixedUpdate()` may get executed any number of times (including 0) in a single frame, depending on a setup. FixedUpdate runs firmly 50 times per second by default, while Update runs roughly 60 times per second (on mobile 30) by default. And lastly, in FixedUpdate never use `Time.deltaTime`, use `Time.fixedDeltaTime`:

`Time.deltaTime` is equal to roughly 1 / 60th of a second (1 frame duration)

`Time.fixedDeltaTime` is roughly 1 / 50th of a second (1 physics update duration)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gravity and RigitBody2D's mass. I recomend you use the RigitBody2D.Addforce() method to jump your caracter, because if you just change the caracter position, the gravity will turn down him to the ground inmediately

This code creates the effect of a "rocketman" that takes off when the user keeps the spacebar pressed:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class jumpAntigravity : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector2 upForce;

    void Start () {
        //Up force set to double of gravity
        upForce = new Vector2(0, 9.8f*2);
    }

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            print("Spacebar is down");
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(upForce);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FixedUpdate can be called multiple times per frame in succession.  This is based on the physics settings for your project.  You can edit this to add more or less accuracy to your physics.

Update is called only 1 time a frame.

So you want to avoid doing logic in the FixedUpdate. If you want to move a rigid body use MovePosition.

From the Unity docs: If Rigidbody interpolation is enabled on the Rigidbody, calling Rigidbody.MovePosition results in a smooth transition between the two positions in any intermediate frames rendered. This should be used if you want to continuously move a rigidbody in each FixedUpdate.